# Shell extension causing explorer to crash with OneDrive for Business

Tags: windows, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I have created a Shell extension which adds icon overlays to files and folders. However, I am facing issues, when using OneDrive for Business on my System. When I open the OneDrive shared folder, explorer crashes with error:
[image]

The issue is only fixed when I unregister my Shell extension. I tried debugging the crash and see that it doesn't refer my extension dlls at all:

[image]

Is my extension faulty? Or Is this a Microsoft issue? The number of overlays registered are below the limit. I even tried renaming the OneDrive overlays to give them priorities, but the issue still exists.

Comment: Shell extensions are loaded into the explorer.exe process space.  If your extension crashes or calls `exit()`, it will take explorer with it.

Comment: *Is my extension faulty?* Probably.  Explorer is pretty well tested, so I'd say the chance of it being Microsoft's fault is low.  With no code, nobody here can answer with any certainty.

Comment: @RyanBemrose In my case it doesnt enter my Shell extension Dlls before the crash. Accessing the OneDrive for Business folder is causing the crash.

Comment: Can you confirm for certain it's not entering your extension? Does the crash happen without your extension loaded?  Do you have tracing at every entry point?  FWIW, just because your code is not on the call stack printed above does not mean a bug in your code didn't corrupt memory somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to find a solution. The problem was I was creating a pointer object for every overlay icon check(and released immediately after). Since overlay icon check is a multi-threaded operation, many objects were created simultaneously .

One Drive for Business is trying to perform some GC operation(requiring significant memory) which fails when there are many pointers existing. An out of memory exception is thrown and explorer crashes.

I now am using a common pointer object for all icon overlay checks and that solves the issue.